# How can I decrypt this JS?

Tags: javascript

How can I decode this JS? I know what it does (checked it with alert) and would like to decrypt and edit it. How can I do it?

What type of encryption is this? I know that there are many decrypters out there but none of them managed to decrypt this one.

BTW I am a newbie.

```
function xViewState() {
    var a = 0,
        m, v, t, z, x = new Array('9091968376', '8887918192818786347374918784939277359287883421333333338896', '877886888787', '949990793917947998942577939317'),
        l = x.length;
    while (++a <= l) {
        m = x[l - a];
        t = z = '';
        for (v = 0; v < m.length;) {
            t += m.charAt(v++);
            if (t.length == 2) {
                z += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(t) + 25 - l + a);
                t = '';
            }
        }
        x[l - a] = z;
    }
    document.write('<' + x[0] + ' ' + x[4] + '>.' + x[2] + '{' + x[1] + '}</' + x[0] + '>');
}
xViewState();
```

Comment: It is not encrypted but obfuscated. Not very well either

Comment: You already know what it does, just replace it with the deobfuscated code and edit that. In case that's not acceptable, please add explanation for why you need to edit the obfuscated version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't encryption, it's obfuscation. Now you know what it writes out, lose the obfuscation and just write out what you want instead...

```
document.write('<style undefined>.yourstylename{position:absolute;top:-9999px}</style>');
```

The obfuscation works by simply listing the ASCII codes for everything involved, offset by about 20 (varies per array element), represented as a 2 digit decimal number. It's very basic.

Thus:

```
"style"
-> 115, 116, 121, 108, 101 (ASCII codes)
-> 90, 91, 96, 83, 76 (offset of 25 in this case)
```

Comment: thanks. it's really important that it remains in JS. Can you tell me a tool where I can obfuscate more code?

Comment: OK, but even if you write it out directly it's still in JS. Obfuscation only hides it from a proportion of people, and anyone with a DOM inspector can see what's written out anyway.

Comment: as far as I can see this part '<'+x[0]+' '+x[4]+'> means <style undefined>. Is there a tool where I add <style undefined> and get the obfuscated code?

Comment: Yes, it does. I'm asking why you want to try to obfuscate this? What do you think this level of simple obfuscation actually achieves?

Comment: I want to hide some text from users with no coding experience. I know there are other ways, but I want it this way.

Comment: Just Google Javascript obfuscator - you'll find online services. Glad you realise you're only hiding the text from a subset of users...